# Is my method for protecting MySQL DB password secure?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, password-encryption

When using:

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password')
```

I have read about the benefits of storing the password part elsewhere (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354457/1704651).

I'm fairly new to PHP and want to know if my method of storing MySQL passwords is secure:

1. Step one, choose a lengthy MySQL Database Password (https://www.random.org/passwords/?num=1&len=24&format=html&rnd=new)
2. Step two, put this in /outsidewebroot/salt.php (my actual salt is longer)

   ```
   <?php $salt = sdcjbdt8veADJbyuQxsfJtYeW7tC5; ?>
   ```
3. Step three, encode password using a temporary PHP file (which is deleted after use):

   ```
   $decrypted = "my decrypted MySQL password"
   $key = $salt;
   $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $decrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
   var_dump($encrypted);
   ```
4. Step four, put this code in .htaccess

   ```
   SetEnv encrypted-password i3NOByNkztBtEbJ8LJMt2GbX9VjMzO2MTYtBXsxyYVI=
   ```
5. Step five, put this code where you need to connect to your database:

   ```
   require_once("../../outside-webroot/salt.php")
   $key = $salt
   $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted-password), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
   $con = mysql_connect('localhost','user',$decrypted)
   ```

The salt in /outsidewebroot/salt.php is the same one that I use for hashing passwords in my database so I only have to include it once for two uses.

The encrypt/decrypt method I saw here: http://ideone.com/yQIAX

I have also seen this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354457/1704651 using a hash instead of the encrypt/decrypt method.

Thank you for your feedback on my method.

Comment: One of the first way to secure it is to connect to mysql db with mysqli or POD with prepared statement. You want to stop injection from happening.

Comment: Instead of putting a lot of effort in the encryption of the mysql password, you should put that effort in making your site secure. I have no problem giving you the IP and mysql password of my site!

Comment: JvdBerg, I'm quite new to this! How have you protected your database? Do you have a link? Kind regards,

Comment: (Also, I did not know about mysqli or POD, as the mysql_connect() command was the first that I read about. Thanks Moe Tsao)

Answer (score 1):

No. If someone can get your files or run programs it's game over:

1. If your web directory is writable, I can simply add a line `echo $decrypted;` above that `mysql_connect()` and get the password.
2. I can copy your files down and edit them there.

Security is a process that you go through, not some library you can link into your program.

- You should store the configuration in the [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php) file so that your program need only `mysql_connect()` (with no arguments). This is a good idea because it may be easier for an attacker to convince your system to print out source code and web-accessible files than print arbitrary fiels on your system.
- On Unixish systems like OSX and Linux, you should make sure you're using unix domain sockets which do not expose your MySQL server to the Internet; someone cannot connect to your MySQL server if it is not on the Internet. This provides some further protection against the "get your files" attack.
- Take care to not permit your web users to create php files (or anything else executable). This provides some protection against the "run programs" attack,
- If I can upload/edit your files, I can do anything they can do, so you should also be careful about your `GRANT` statements that you put in your MySQL server: If only the administrator needs to do certain `INSERT` or `DELETE` to certain tables, consider running the admin scripts as a separate web-user with separate rights. If your scripts cannot delete all your data, then I as an attacker cannot either.

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of security is that if you're not certain you're secure, then you probably aren't.

The next version of PHP (v5.5) will have a set of functions built-in that provide standardised password hashing. Once this version is released, that will be the only recommended way to handle passwords.

In the meanwhile, you can download a compatibility library that implements the same functions for current PHP versions. Download it from here: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

See also: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/PHP-5-5-should-reduce-password-sloppiness-1707835.html for reference.